# Listbox not always adding item using Windows Azure MobileServiceCollection with WP8

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, listbox, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Windows Azure Mobile Services to store and retrieve data in my Windows Phone 8 app. This is a bit of a complicated issue so I will do my best to explain it.

Firstly I'm using raw push notifications to receive a message and when it receives the message it updates a listbox in my app. When I open my app, navigate to the page with the `ListBox` and receive a push notification the `ListBox` updates fine. If I press back, then navigate to the same page with the `ListBox`, the push notification is received, the code to update the `ListBox` executes with no errors yet the `ListBox` doesn't update. I have checked that the same code runs using the `OnNavigatedTo` handler in both scenarios, but it seems like the `ListBox` does not bind correctly in the second instance when I press back and then re-navigate to the same page. Here are some code snippets:

MobileServiceCollection declarations:

```cs
public class TodoItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

}

private MobileServiceCollection<ToDoItem, ToDoItem> TodoItems;
private IMobileServiceTable<TodoItem> todoTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>();
```

Push Notification Received Handler:

```cs
void PushChannel_HttpNotificationReceived(object sender, HttpNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        string message;

        using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(e.Notification.Body))
        {
            message = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }


        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
          {

              var todoItem = new TodoItem
              {
                Text = message,
              };
              ToDoItems.Add(todoItem);

           }
    );

     }
```

I have tried using:

```cs
ListItems.UpdateLayout();
```

and

```cs
ListItems.ItemsSource = null;
ListItems.ItemsSource = ToDoItems;
```

before and after the code in the above procedure that adds the `ToDoItem` but it didn't help.

The following procedure is called in my `OnNavigatedTo` event handler, and refreshes the `Listbox` and assigns `ToDoItems` as the items source:

```cs
private async void RefreshTodoItems()
    {       
        try
        {
            ToDoItems = await todoTable
                .ToCollectionAsync();
        }
        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error loading items", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }

        ListItems.ItemsSource = ToDoItems;                      

    }
```

The above procedure is `async` but I have made sure it completes before receiving any notifications. Even so, as mentioned above when I open the app, navigate to the page that shows the `ListBox` it updates fine. When I press back, navigate to the same page again, it doesn't work. When I back out of the app, re-open it, navigate to the page with the `ListBox`, it works again, and then fails if I press back and re-open the page. So it seems the `ListBox` is not binding to `ToDoItems` correctly when I press back and navigate to the same page.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think I have found the issue. I have to close the push channel on navigatedfrom and so it opens a new one when I come back to it and it works fine. Closing the push channel isn't in any WP or Azure doco examples I've been looking at so I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify your approach a bit to use [Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc278072%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and the MVVM model to bind your model to your view.

It might look like a bit of effort initially but will save you a lot of debugging hours later on.

Just follow the below steps

1. Create a new class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged
2. Add the below method implementation

   ```
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
           private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
           {
               PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
               if (null != handler)
               {
                   handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
               }
           }
   ```
3. Add `public ObservableCollection<TodoItem> TodoItems{ get; private set; }` and initialize it in the constructor.
4. Every PhoneApplicationPage has a DataContext member. Assing it to a singleton instance of the above class that you create.
5. In the XAML, add the property `ItemsSource="{Binding TodoItems}"` to the list.
6. In the DataTemplate of the list use `ItemsSource="{Binding Text}"` for the control you wish to display this value on. ( e.g. TextBlock )
7. Now whenever you add elements to the collection, it will be reflected in the UI, and [vice-versa](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc278072%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Directionofthedataflow).